# Проверочное слово

Tags: орфография

"Вести за руку" - как проверить букву С?

Answer (score 3):

В этом случае следует знать, что существует переход Д-СТ.
Ведет - вести, проведать - навестить, сведение - известие, вестимо - ведомо, падкий (падь) - пасть, сладкий - сласть, бредет - брести, грядет - грясти, род - рост (корни слов разошлись немного в значениях, но безусловная связь остается, см. Этим. словарь Крылова), крадет - красть...
Надеюсь, моя подсказка поможет Вам!

Answer (score 2):

В этом случае можно провести "отрицательную" проверку. У нас ведь выбор из двух букв - З или С. Можно с уверенностью показать, когда по значению надо писать З: везти - везу. Если по значению "перевозки" вам не подходят, по остаточному принципу надо писать С.